# MVVMCross - Use converted value in other converter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to use two converters together in my code. One is custom, the other one is the built-in converter.

My goal is to use my converter-modified value as a parameter in another MvvmCross converter.
So, I want to get System.Drawing.Color() first via DueDateTintValueConverter, then I will give it to  MvvmCross' ["**NativeColor"** converter.](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters#the-mvx-color-valueconverters)

And finally, the custom binder named **TintColor** will handle the setting of the Android coloring.

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewWatch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:tint="?attr/color_dueDate_normal"
    app:MvxBind="TintColor NativeColor(DueDate), Converter=DueDateTint"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clock" />
```

But, I run into a binding error here getting **"InvalidCastException, nullable DateTime cannot cast to Color".**
It means DueDate remains the same regardless of the DueDateTintConverter.

How can I find a solution for this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me and like an unsupported use case. Create a new Converter or just do the conversion in your ViewModel.

Comment: I did it that way now.